# xStream deep nesting. Lazy initialization

Tags: java, nested, xstream, self-reference

Imagine the following class, representing the Vagon:

```
    class Vagon {
            int id;
            Vagon nextVagon;
    }
```

it has only two fields: an id and reference to next class instance.
So, imagine we have list of this objects representing train ( first constructor arg is the id, second - **next**Vagon ref ):

```
            Vagon vagon5 = new Vagon( 5, null );
            Vagon vagon4 = new Vagon( 4, vagon5 );
            Vagon vagon3 = new Vagon( 3, vagon4 );
            Vagon vagon2 = new Vagon( 2, vagon3 );
            Vagon vagon1 = new Vagon( 1, vagon2 );
            Vagon vagon0 = new Vagon( 0, vagon1 );
```

Where the vagon0 - is the last, next to him vagon1 and so on.
So, when i serialise List of this vagons using xstream i got smth like this:

```
        <list>
          <TrainTest_-Vagon>
            <id>0</id>
            <nextVagon>
              <id>1</id>
              <nextVagon>
                <id>2</id>
                <nextVagon>
                  <id>3</id>
                  <nextVagon>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <nextVagon>
                      <id>5</id>
                    </nextVagon>
                  </nextVagon>
                </nextVagon>
              </nextVagon>
            </nextVagon>
          </TrainTest_-Vagon>
          <TrainTest_-Vagon reference="../TrainTest_-Vagon/nextVagon"/>
          <TrainTest_-Vagon reference="../TrainTest_-Vagon/nextVagon/nextVagon"/>
          <TrainTest_-Vagon reference="../TrainTest_-Vagon/nextVagon/nextVagon/nextVagon"/>
          <TrainTest_-Vagon reference="../TrainTest_-Vagon/nextVagon/nextVagon/nextVagon/nextVagon"/>
          <TrainTest_-Vagon reference="../TrainTest_-Vagon/nextVagon/nextVagon/nextVagon/nextVagon/nextVagon"/>
        </list>
```

So IN fact - I have first big vagon0 that includes within itself  all other vagons, and the other list members - are refereces.

The problems are
1) if list size is very big xStream can't serialize it due to stack limiting - i'm just getting StackOverflow Error.
2) Output is very hard to read: i would like having smthing like that:

```
                <list>
                  <TrainTest_-Vagon>
                    <id>0</id>
                    <nextVagon reference="..ref to vagon1..">
                  </TrainTest_-Vagon>
                  <TrainTest_-Vagon>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <nextVagon reference="..ref to vagon2..">
                  </TrainTest_-Vagon>
                  <TrainTest_-Vagon>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <nextVagon reference="..ref to vagon3..">
                  </TrainTest_-Vagon>
                  <TrainTest_-Vagon>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <nextVagon reference="..ref to vagon4..">
                  </TrainTest_-Vagon>
                  <TrainTest_-Vagon>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <nextVagon reference="..ref to vagon5..">
                  </TrainTest_-Vagon>
                  <TrainTest_-Vagon>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <nextVagon reference="..null..">
                  </TrainTest_-Vagon>
                </list>
```

So, from tech point of view, I think that we are speaking of lazy marshalling - first marsal vagons leaving the "nextVagon" blank - and then when we will have all train in memory insert the refereces.
Is there any way to do this in xStream or i will have to write my own Converter to TrainList?

**EDIT:** In real life situation Vagon class can have member ref to previousVagon as well, or even list of vagons that **can** be connected to it, so there is no way we can solve this just changing the list order ( serializing sequence ) - we should assume that each of the vagons have reference to another.

Answer (score 0):

If it seems feasible, consider reverting the list before serialization - this would xstream to render XML similar to what you expect.

Comment: It will work in this situation, but in the real life each vagon have not only nextVagon member, but also previousVagon link - so there is no way to find one without reference to set it like prime ( first ) one

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is with your own `Converter`. XStream does not have any built-in lazy marshalling mechanism.

Regarding converting to a list: if Vagons can have references to previous and next Vagons, it is not always possible to order them such that you have already marshalled the previous/next references. If you haven't already marshalled a reference then XStream will marshal it in place and you will still get a nested layout.

Possible workarounds if you really don't want to make a Converter:

- It sounds like your Vagons might be a Tree structure. If you remove the `previousVagon` references you could order them as a list from the leaves upward.
- You can use `omitField` to prevent XStream from serializing the previous/next references, but then you will have to store the references separately (eg. a map) and repair them after unmarshalling. Also the references won't show in the Vagon list because they're omitted. You'll get something like:

  ```
  <VagonHolder>
    <vagonList>
      <Vagon>
        <id>1</id>
      </Vagon>
      <Vagon>
        <id>2</id>
      </Vagon>
      <Vagon>
        <id>3</id>
      </Vagon>
    </vagonList>
    <nextVagonsMap>
      <entry>
        <Vagon reference="../../../vagonList/Vagon"/>
        <Vagon reference="../../../vagonList/Vagon[2]"/>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <Vagon reference="../../../vagonList/Vagon[2]"/>
        <Vagon reference="../../../vagonList/Vagon[3]"/>
      </entry>
    </nextVagonsMap>
  </VagonHolder>
  ```